# Singular / plural adjective

Tags: adjectives, american-english, nouns, apostrophe

What is basically difference between adding a apostrophe to a singular adjective *ghost* like **ghost's** and without it like **ghosts**

Comment: *Ghost* is a noun

Comment: [This is the basic English possessive.](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/english-grammar-usage-possessives.html) ("the ghost's haunting appearance"), and basic English plural ("the ghosts haunted that house for many years")

Comment: If you haven't learned what a _noun_ is, or studied the simple possessive in English, your instructor is failing miserably! Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us, in your question, why you think _ghost_ is an adjective.

Answer (score 1):

**Ghost's** is possessive.  Here is an example of it being used:

> The **ghost's** body disappeared into the wall.

**Ghosts**, on the other hand, is the plural form of *ghost*. Here's an example:

> I saw two **ghosts** yesterday.

Comment: And then there is the possessive plural: `The two ghosts' bodies disappeared into the wall.`